# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createComponent' of undefined in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in angular 4 and i am using "dynamic component loading" for making project, but there is issue of createComponent for loading component.

[image: component]
In above image there is four sections.

1. Top section(headerComponent)
2. Events section (EventsComponent) 
   Note:- Event Section has two dynamic component (2.1, 2.2)
   2.1. Event detail section(EventDetailComponent) of particular event
   2.2. User form section (UserFormComponent)

> When click on "Event" tab from top header we are hitting event api and
>   showing events in left side bar and then hit event detail api load
>   "2.1 event details" screen. when click on show user then again load
>   "2.2 User Form" dynamic form.

**Issue:-**
when hitting the api of event detail of particular event and api is now waiting state and then user click on "create event" tab then it is going to create event screen and again user click on event tab then showing createComponent Error for event detail. also clicking on add user button then again showing the same error.

**Code:-**

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.getEventList('init');
}

public getEventList(listsource) {
  this.appService.getJsonRequest(AppSettings.EVENT_LIST).subscribe(result => {
    if (result.status === 200  && result.events) {
      this.events = result.events;
      this.publicEvents = result.events;
      this.events[0].selected = true;
      this.selectedEVentInfo = this.events[0];
      this.noImgFlag = true;
      this.eventDetailFlag = false;
        this.eventDetailInfo(listsource); 
    } else {
      this.loaderMsg = AppSettings.EVENT_LIST_ERROR_MSG;
    }
    // this.loaderFlag = false;
  }, err => {
    this.loaderMsg = AppSettings.EVENT_LIST_ERROR_MSG;
    this.loaderFlag = false;
    this.snackBar.open(err, AppSettings.CLOSE, {
      duration: AppSettings.DURATION,
    });
  });
}


  eventDetailInfo  (event, source: String = null) { // event detail
   console.log('### Get event detail information');
   if (this.eventDetailFlag === false) {
    if ((source === 'list' || source === 'delete' || source === 'stripe') && this.ed !== undefined) { // testing needed
      console.log('clear');
      this.ed.clear();
    }

        let edCompFactory: ComponentFactory<any>;
        edCompFactory = this.compFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(EdComponent);
        const componentRef = this.ed.createComponent(edCompFactory);
        (<EdComponent>componentRef.instance).event = this.selectedEVentInfo;
      }
   }
 }
```

**Code of Add User:-**

```
expandAddEventMember(fullWidth) {
if (this.fullWidth === true && fullWidth === true) {
  console.log('Before');
    if (this.am !== undefined) {
      this.am.clear();
    }
  // setTimeout(() => {
    let amCompFactory: ComponentFactory<any>;
    amCompFactory = this.compFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AmComponent);
    const componentRef = this.am.createComponent(amCompFactory);
    (<AmComponent>componentRef.instance).event = this.selectedEVentInfo;
    this.fullWidth = false;
  // }, 100);
  }
}
```

**Error:-**
[image]

Here is my entryComponent

```
  entryComponents: [
AppComponent,
ForgotModalComponent,
EventDetailsModalComponent,
AddManagerModalComponent,
AddAdminModalComponent,
CopyLinkModalComponent,
OrderSummaryModalComponent,
EventPreviewModalComponent,
PaidMemberModalComponent,
SendMessageModalComponent,
TicketInfoModalComponent,
AddPaidMemberModalComponent,
MessageModalComponent,
TicketCheckInDetailModalComponent,
SaleItemModalComponent,
SaleItemListModalComponent,
ApmComponent,
PmComponent,
AsmComponent,
SlmComponent,
TiComponent,
EdComponent,
AmComponent,
SihComponent,
ImageModalComponent,
GoogleMapModalComponent
]
```

Comment: what is `ed` and `am`, can you post its declaration?

Comment: Did you add `AmComponent` to `entryComponents[]` array in the module that contains it?

Comment: ed means eventDetail and am addMember.

Comment: yes i added AmComponent and EdComponent component in app.module.ts file

Comment: @SharmaVikram can you post the code for them? The error you got looks like they are not instantiated

Comment: @Narm means not just if you added the components to the module 'declarations' array, but also to 'entryComponents'. Components that need to be dynamically created by code (instead of inside a template) need to be added to that array. Seeing the error, it seems that the component couldn't be resolved, which I'm pretty sure is due to the fact that the component is not registered in entryComponents. Check that.

Comment: i have added in entryComponent please check it in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure that `am` and `em` are instantiated before creating the component.I assume that they can be undefined, since in your code, you already check if `am` or `em` is instantiated `if(this.am !== undefined)` at some stage (before calling `clear`), but not for calling `createComponent`. It's just that you need to include our `createComponent` code inside the `if`

```
  eventDetailInfo(event, source: String = null)
  { // event detail
    console.log('### Get event detail information');
    if (this.eventDetailFlag === false)
    {
      if ((source === 'list' || source === 'delete' || source === 'stripe') && this.ed !== undefined)
      { // testing needed
        console.log('clear');
        this.ed.clear();
        /*}  <======= Remove this bracket*/

        let edCompFactory: ComponentFactory<any>;
        edCompFactory = this.compFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(EdComponent);
        const componentRef = this.ed.createComponent(edCompFactory);
        (<EdComponent>componentRef.instance).event = this.selectedEVentInfo;
      }/* <========== Add it here */

    }
  }
```

Same for **addUser**

```
  expandAddEventMember(fullWidth)
  {
    if (this.fullWidth === true && fullWidth === true)
    {
      console.log('Before');
      if (this.am !== undefined)
      {
        this.am.clear();
        /* } <=== Remove this bracket **/
        let amCompFactory: ComponentFactory<any>;
        amCompFactory = this.compFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AmComponent);
        const componentRef = this.am.createComponent(amCompFactory);
        (<AmComponent>componentRef.instance).event = this.selectedEVentInfo;
        this.fullWidth = false;
      } /** <==== Add it here */

    }
  }
```

**Edit**: Regarding your comment about normalizing it, you should probably open another question since it's a completely different problem.  The following piece of codemay not work (not tested) but could give you an idea of an approach

```
@Injectable()
export class CompFactoryHelper
{
  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver)
  {

  }

public createAndAddComponent(containerRef: ViewContainerRef, eventInfo : any, type: any)
   {
        containerRef.clear();
        let compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(type);
        const componentRef = containerRef.createComponent(compFactory);
        (componentRef.instance as any).event = eventInfo;
   }
}
```

and in your components

```
 expandAddEventMember(fullWidth)
  {
    if (this.fullWidth === true && fullWidth === true)
    {
      console.log('Before');
      if (this.am !== undefined)
      {
        this.compFactoryHelper.createAndAddComponent(this.am,  this.selectedEVentInfo, AmComponent);

      } 

    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks @David, it is working, let me test one more time, i just need to confirm with you, can i normalize the above code ?  because createComponent used in many places.

Comment: @Sharma Vikram I added some piece of code that you can use as a starting point. Not tested